# The C Programming Language Exercise 1.16 - Loop works in standalone program but not in exercise program

Tags: c, loops

Sorry if this has been asked before. I've found various (and probably way more efficient) solutions to this exercise but I'm kind of puzzled by mine in particular not producing any useful output.

This is the original code from the example in chapter 1.9

```
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* print longest input line */

main() {
    int len;        /* current line length */
    int max;        /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)    /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length */
int getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i=0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char to[], char from[]) {
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

The task is to `revise the main routine of the longest-line program so it will correctly print the length of arbitrarily long input lines, and as much as possible of the text`. Some solutions modify  `getline()` but it reads like I'm supposed to modify `main()` so that's what I decided to try.

What came to mind is to implement a secondary line length counter and compare it to MAXLINE to decide what message to print. I came up with a fairly simple loop in a separate little program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int c, i, ll;

    ll = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)  
        for (i = 0; (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            if (i > ll)
                ll = i;

    printf("%d\n", longest);
}
```

This works fine on its own, but when I add it back in, it outputs 0 every time. If I move the loop above the other one, I get no output at all. I compiled with GCC with `-ansi` and `-pedantic` flags and there were no warnings so likely something simple is flying over my head (It's also my first language).

modified `main()`:

```
main() {
    int i,c, ll;    /* additional line length counter */
    int len;        /* current line length */
    int max;        /* maximum length seen so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    
    ll = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
            if (i > ll)
                ll = i;
    
    if (max > 0 && ll > max)
        printf("Line length limit exceeded (%d characters), output will be truncated.\n%s...\n", ll, longest);
    else if (max > 0 && ll < max)   /* there was a line */
        printf("%s\n", longest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first loop has already consumed your input. `getchar()` reports there is nothing more to get.

Comment: Indeed you didn' process the input that wasn't EOF before getting another character to check the `for` loop end condition. Why do you need a `for` loop nested in a `while` loop?

Comment: Note that using `main()` for the definition of `int main(void)` (or, at a pinch, `int main()`) is obsolete.  It has not been valid, standard C for the whole of the current millennium.  If your textbook is teaching you to use `main()`, it is too old and should be replaced.  If your tutor is teaching you to use `main()`, they are teaching you badly and you should find a better teacher if at all possible.  Since K&R 2nd Edition uses `main()`, it too should not be used for learning modern C.

Comment: @WeatherVane Initially I tried to use an `if` statement inside a for loop and use it to reset the value of `i` but that didn't work at all, this was the only arrangement that worked reliably.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the correct `main` function declaration.
2. Initialize your variables.
3. You try to consume data twice from the stream.
4. One loop is enough.

```
int main(void) {
    int c, i = 0, ll = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        if(c != '\n') 
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if( i > ll) 
        {
            ll = i;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", longest);
}
```

```
#define MAXLINELENGTH   100

int main(void) {
    int c, i = 0, ll = 0;
    char longestline[MAXLINELENGTH];
    char currentline[MAXLINELENGTH];

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        if(c != '\n') 
        {
            if(i < MAXLINELENGTH - 1) currentline[i] = c;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        if( i > ll) 
        {
            if(i >= MAXLINELENGTH - 1) currentline[MAXLINELENGTH - 1] = 0;
            else currentline[i] = 0;
            strcpy(longestline, currentline);
            ll = i;
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Longest line length = %d\nLine = \"%s\"\n", ll, longestline);
}
```

Comment: That's simpler than I expected, I haven't encountered `continue` and `strcpy` yet but I'll keep it in mind, thanks.